# Как программы относятся к монтированным дискам?

Tags: windows, ntfs, диск, монтирование

Хочу вынести папку Users на отдельный диск и примотнировать его как ntfs-папку вместо оригинальной. Вопрос в том, насколько это хорошая идея? Win7 и Win10.

Вопрос возник из-за того, что, теоретически, подобного результата можно добиться с помощью символьных ссылок. Однако, мне известны случаи, когда некоторые программы символьные ссылки за папки не считают и просто удаляют, создавая на их месте новую папку. Возникнут ли подобные проблемы в случае с диском?

Вообще смысл заключается в переносе профилей пользователей на другой физический диск.

Comment: в винде ты просто в реестре меняешь путь к папке пользователя и все, никаких симлинков не нужно, монтировать тоже не нужно. просто у тебя папка юзера была в c:\четатам, стала d:\четатам -  собсно вот для семерки, но это работало еще со времен XP http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-change-user-profile-default-location-in-windows-7

Comment: @strangeqargo, система не свежеустановленная, у кучи программ в настройках может быть прописан старый вариант. А ещё куча может просто хардкодить что-нибудь. По переносу гуглятся варианты, где говорится после изменения в реестре перелопатить весь реестр с заменой старых путей новыми (причём несколько раз с перезаходом в систему - пока не кончатся, и руками проверить, т. к. утилиты заменяют не всё), либо создать символьные ссылки.

Comment: ты можешь легко проверить это просто сделав копию и сменив путь, если не взлетает, верни обратно и попробуй симлинки. максимум что может отвалиться, имхо - пути к сохраненным файлам (и то, жестко захардкоженные, а не привязанные к переменным окружения). Я так переносил папки и каких-то страшных проблем не было. Опять же, если у тебя софт весь современнный - то юзай симлинки сразу, они должны их уважать

Comment: Вот только вчера перетащил с помощью скрипта папку ограниченного пользователя на диск D:\. А ещё до этого 10 компьютерных классов с 80-ю прогами так же работают с перенесённым профилем студента тоже на D:\ - и всё гладко. Win7Pro.

Comment: Да, всё через robocopy и mklink. Листинг могу кинуть.

Comment: @donRumata, когда я однажды попытался Program Files заменить символьной ссылкой, даже часа не прошло, как обновление Хромиумоорперы её удалило и создало папку с единственной подпапкой. Вроде вполне новая программа? Ну и с таким же я встречался в других ситуациях - символьная ссылка дропается, создаётся папка.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спорить не буду, не встречал такого поведения. А отрубить обновления и вообще не ставить линий софт - вариант? И как вообще эти компы используются? Лично я пришёл к мысли об атомарном обновлении (всё снести и поставить заново) всей системы, реально легче.

Comment: @Arhad, так как раз про это я и спрашиваю.

Comment: @donRumata, не, идея другая. Если системный диск [портится](/q/572801/178988), то сохранить профиль пользователя независимо от системы, чтобы потом из него можно было порастаскивать что-то нужное в актуальном состоянии, а не то, что сохранилось в бекапе.

Comment: @Qwertiy, на другой винт, который тоже может навернуться (у моего клиента был wd black, который сдох через 3 дня после покупки)? Вот сохранять профиль в сеть - это более интересная идея. Но для этого уже не симлинки нужны.

Comment: @strangeqargo смена пути к профилю через реестр жесточайше ломает 10-й Store, и вообще universal apps, включая системные :(

Comment: @PashaPash печально ( кеклятый микрософт, даже это испортили

Comment: @Qwertiy олсо http://superuser.com/questions/1074052/mount-secondary-disk-as-program-files-folder-on-windows-10/1074056 вариант без симлинков, одни маунты

Comment: @PashaPash, вероятно, в случае доступности по обоим путям такой проблемы нет?

Comment: @strangeqargo, там описание технической возможности. Технически у меня и с символьной ссылкой получалось (создать пустой каталог и символьную ссылку на него, перезагрузиться в линукс, переместить файлы в пустой каталог, удалить опустевший старый каталог, переименовать символьную ссылку, перезагрузиться обратно), но проблема зарылась в том, что не всем программам понравилась символьная ссылка - всё проработало полчаса, пока опера не обновилась, снеся всё. С монтированием диска я пока не попробовал, но судя по комментариям тут, такой проблемы возникнуть не должно :)

Comment: по идее не должно, странно что мы забыли про монтирование виндовое

Comment: @Qwertiy да, если старый путь остается - то все ок. проблема только в том, что я пытался перенести профиль как раз для переноса кэша маркетплейса - он начал место есть на SSD. :(